# Is Memcached Running without Throwing Notice/Warning

Tags: php, memcached, custom-error-handling

After some experimenting trying to determine whether memcached is actually running it appears that the only way to do this is by creating a custom error handler to suppress the notice/warning thrown by Memcache::connect

I already have an error handler for my application that doesn't respond to this in a way that would suppress the error.

So if I have a method, say `checkRunning()` like so:

```
public function checkRunning() {
    $test = new Memcache;
    return @$test->connect(CACHE_HOSTNAME, CACHE_PORT);
}
```

How can I apply a custom error handler to this method so that it just returns false, without overriding my existing error handler?

Comment: The `@` should perfectly suppress any errors thrown by this. That will still invoke your error handler, yes. The error handler has to check for itself whether it should act or not.

Comment: Note: MemCache is not Memcached. Those are two different things as I had to find out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your error handler is simply not written correctly. Take particular note of this:

> [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless - however you are still able to read the current value of [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and act appropriately. Of particular note is that this value will be `0` if the statement that caused the error was prepended by the [`@` error-control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).
>
> http://php.net/set_error_handler

If your error handler obeyed the `@` operator, your code should be fine.

Comment: The @ error-control operator does not suppress this error. The error handler returns 2 and 8 for Notice and Warning regardless of whether I use the @ symbol.

Comment: Yes, the error handler will still be invoked. But the `error_reporting` flag will be set to `0` if `@` was used, so it's up to your error handler to check for that flag and not do anything.

Comment: Yeah I read some more of the comments and found that I need to look for `error_reporting() == 0` added that to my handler and it works like a charm.  This is the only place in my entire framework that I use the @ symbol so I didn't realize that the handler didn't manage it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a comment about an alternative solution on the PHP ste from tom at all dash community dot de

http://php.net/manual/de/memcache.connect.php

---

There is a not-so-obvious way to check whether or not a MemCache-Server is available.

Using ($memCache->connect() == false) **will wait for a timeout** if it can't connect. If you got a high-traffic site this may not be an option. So when the server is down, you may want to avoid waiting for this timeout on every request and instead try to reconnect only once every X seconds.

If so, this code may help:

```
<?php
$memCache = new \Memcache();
$memCache->addServer($host, $port);
$stats = @$memCache->getExtendedStats();
$available = (bool) $stats["$host:$port"];
if ($available && @$memCache->connect($host, $port))
    // MemCache is there
else
    // go on without MemCache
?>
```

The result of getExtendedStats() is an array. The information is cached and maintained by MemCache itself. If the server is not available, the result will be FALSE.

Even if the result is not false, the server may still not be available. Thus you need to check for connect() != false too, but only if the first check returns TRUE, thus avoiding the 1 second timeout in most cases.
Both getExtendedStats() and connect() issue notices/warnings if the server is not there. Thus you have to mute both calls.

Do NOT use getServerStatus() for this purpose: the result is cached on server-start and will not recognize when the connection to the server is lost (or reestablished) in between.

Comment: This will ALSO call your error handler. You might want to temporarily disable it and return to the default handler.